# Javascript bug? Maximum stack of anonymous functions per line

Tags: javascript, function, testing

Bear with me on this.

tl;dr My code only works when I put newlines between function arguments.  Is there a maximum on stack size or function declarations per line in javascript?

I've been testing a hypothesis of mine that if you're creative enough, all javascript functions can be re-written (by sacrificing speed and readability) without using:

- Spaces or newlines

  - (By extension, this prevents the use of many keywords)
- Declared datatypes (e.g. `""`,`[]`,`0`,`false`,`{}`,etc.)
- More than one statement per scope
- Operators of any sort (including logical and relational)

Or, in layman's terms, the whole function should match `/^[a-zA-Z(){}.,]*$/`.

The biggest challenge I've faced so far in the process of proving this hypothesis (I haven't gotten to regular expressions, that ought to be fun) is dealing with mathematics, which is heavily dependent on operators and numbers.

I've written up functions which follow my parameters and:

- calculate basic arithmetic (`add(a,b) //a+b`)
- form integers (`digs(one,three,six,eight) //1368`)
- get and set object properties (`setprop(a,b,c) //a[b]=c`)

The general idea is to structure functions like below, to make algorithms marginally more readable and writable in this manner:

```
function(...){(function(add,morefuncs...){algorithm...})(function(){...},morefuncs...)}
```

My functions work individually, as well as in this form when there are few enough of them, but as I've added more, I've noticed an extremely peculiar bug:

```
//For some reason, this breaks:
func(arguments,...,f1,f2)

//And this doesn't:
func(arguments,...,
    f1,f2)
```

Given the large amount of anonymous functions my code requires, I presumed there was a maximum number of anonymous functions javascript can handle in one line, but I can't find any documentation that says this or otherwise.

Here are three versions of my code:

**VERSION 1:  Without newlines, Doesn't work**

```
(function(){return(function(domath){return(domath)(function(getprop,setprop,add,sub,mlt,div,cct,digs,zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine){console.log(getprop,setprop)})})((function(){return(function(m,i,o,c,g,h){return(function(a,d){return(function(s,t){return(function(r,n){return(function(f){return(f).apply(null,Array(g,h,function(x,y){return(r(a(x,y)))},function(x,y){return(r(s(x,y)))},function(x,y){return(r(m(x,y)))},d,c,function(){return(Number(Object.keys(arguments).map(function(k){return(g(arguments,k))}).join(String())))}).concat(n))})})(function(x){return(Number(x.toFixed(t)))},Array(Number(),Math.exp(Number()),Array(Number(),String()).toString().length,Array(Number(),Number()).toString().length,Boolean(Math.exp(Number())).toString().length,Boolean(Number()).toString().length,Array(Boolean(),String()).toString().length,Array(Boolean(),Number()).toString().length,Array(Boolean(),Number(),String()).toString().length,Array(Boolean(),Number(),Number()).toString().length))})(function(x,y){return(Math.log(d(Math.exp(x),Math.exp(y))))},Number(c(String(o),String(Number()))))})(function(x,y){return(Math.log(m(Math.exp(x),Math.exp(y))))},function(x,y){return(m(x,i(y)))})})(function(x,y){return(Math.log(Math.pow(Math.exp(x),y)))},function(x){return(Math.pow(x,Array().indexOf(Number())))},Math.exp(Number()),function(x,y){return(Array(x,y).join(String()))},function(x,y){return(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x,y).value)},function(x,y,z){Object.defineProperty(x,y,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array(z,Number()).slice(Number(),Math.exp(Number())),Number()))})})())})()
```

Logs `function anonymous(urn) function anonymous(urn)` on Chrome.  (What is "urn"?  I don't have any variables by that name, and the only instances of that string are in "return" keywords.)

Logs `function anonymous() function anonymous()` on Firefox.

**VERSION 2:  With one newline, works**

```
(function(){return(function(domath){return(domath)(function(getprop,setprop,add,sub,mlt,div,cct,digs,zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine){console.log(getprop,setprop)})})((function(){return(function(m,i,o,c,g,h){return(function(a,d){return(function(s,t){return(function(r,n){return(function(f){return(f).apply(null,Array(g,h,function(x,y){return(r(a(x,y)))},function(x,y){return(r(s(x,y)))},function(x,y){return(r(m(x,y)))},d,c,function(){return(Number(Object.keys(arguments).map(function(k){return(g(arguments,k))}).join(String())))}).concat(n))})})(function(x){return(Number(x.toFixed(t)))},Array(Number(),Math.exp(Number()),Array(Number(),String()).toString().length,Array(Number(),Number()).toString().length,Boolean(Math.exp(Number())).toString().length,Boolean(Number()).toString().length,Array(Boolean(),String()).toString().length,Array(Boolean(),Number()).toString().length,Array(Boolean(),Number(),String()).toString().length,Array(Boolean(),Number(),Number()).toString().length))})(function(x,y){return(Math.log(d(Math.exp(x),Math.exp(y))))},Number(c(String(o),String(Number()))))})(function(x,y){return(Math.log(m(Math.exp(x),Math.exp(y))))},function(x,y){return(m(x,i(y)))})})(function(x,y){return(Math.log(Math.pow(Math.exp(x),y)))},function(x){return(Math.pow(x,Array().indexOf(Number())))},Math.exp(Number()),function(x,y){return(Array(x,y).join(String()))},
function(x,y){return(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x,y).value)},function(x,y,z){Object.defineProperty(x,y,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array(z,Number()).slice(Number(),Math.exp(Number())),Number()))})})())})()
```

Logs `function anonymous(x, y) function anonymous(x, y, z)`.

**VERSION 3:  Beautified for your viewing pleasure**

```
(function() {
  return (function(domath) {
      return (domath)(function(getprop, setprop, add, sub, mlt, div, cct, digs, zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine) {
          console.log(getprop, setprop)
      })
  })((function() {
      return (function(m, i, o, c, g, h) { //multiplication, inverse, one, concatenation, getObjectProperty, setObjectProperty
          return (function(a, d) { //add, divide
              return (function(s, t) { //subtract, ten
                  return (function(r, n) { //roundToTenDigits (fix for negatives), numbers (so you can call numbers as variables)
                      return (function(f) { //makes it so you don't have to re-initialize the functions every time you do math
                          return (f).apply(null, Array(g, h, function(x, y) {
                              return (r(a(x, y))) //modifies addition (rounds results like -2.999999999996)
                          }, function(x, y) {
                              return (r(s(x, y))) //modifies subtraction
                          }, function(x, y) {
                              return (r(m(x, y))) //modifies multiplication
                          }, d, c, function() { //makes a number out of its digits
                              return (Number(Object.keys(arguments).map(function(k) {
                                  return (g(arguments, k))
                              }).join(String())))
                          }).concat(n)) //adds all the numbers to the arguments array
                      })
                  })(function(x) {
                      return (Number(x.toFixed(t)))
                  }, Array(Number(), Math.exp(Number()), Array(Number(), String()).toString().length, Array(Number(), Number()).toString().length, Boolean(Math.exp(Number())).toString().length, Boolean(Number()).toString().length, Array(Boolean(), String()).toString().length, Array(Boolean(), Number()).toString().length, Array(Boolean(), Number(), String()).toString().length, Array(Boolean(), Number(), Number()).toString().length))
              })(function(x, y) {
                  return (Math.log(d(Math.exp(x), Math.exp(y))))
              }, Number(c(String(o), String(Number()))))
          })(function(x, y) {
              return (Math.log(m(Math.exp(x), Math.exp(y))))
          }, function(x, y) {
              return (m(x, i(y)))
          })
      })(function(x, y) {
          return (Math.log(Math.pow(Math.exp(x), y)))
      }, function(x) {
          return (Math.pow(x, Array().indexOf(Number())))
      }, Math.exp(Number()), function(x, y) {
          return (Array(x, y).join(String()))
      }, function(x, y) {
          return (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x, y).value)
      }, function(x, y, z) {
          Object.defineProperty(x, y, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array(z, Number()).slice(Number(), Math.exp(Number())), Number()))
      })
  })())
})()
```

I don't think I can call this a bug in javascript, given the nature of what I'm trying to accomplish, but it would be good to have documentation on the maximum number of anonymous functions per line if one exists (for minimizing large libraries, for instance).

Has anyone seen anything like this before?  Any advice?

Thanks so much.

P.S.  Please avoid "your hypothesis is dumb" answers.  That'd be nice.

**EDIT:  Just an update on the conversation so far:**

To clarify, I DO NOT want it to output `function anonymous() function anonymous()`.  I want it to output `function anonymous(x, y) function anonymous(x, y, z)`.

- Chrome v43 doesn't work on Windows 8.1, Windows 7 or Mac OS X 10.
- Firefox 39 doesn't work.
- Chrome Canary v45 works perfectly.  Another user says v44 also works.
- I'm hoping to have cross-browser compatibility if possible.
- I am the author of this code.
- If you think my code is written in a weird way, you clearly have not read this whole question.

Comment: It might have something to do with an implicit `;` on newlines.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/6252067/47589

Comment: I don't think so, because the newline is between arguments.  Calling `function(a,;b)` definitely does not work.

Comment: Version 1 works just fine for me. Chrome 44.0.2403.89 (64-bit), OS X 10.10.

Comment: Muhammad please read the whole thing.  Siguza, are you using a console, jsfiddle, raw HTML, what?

Comment: So am I, but I'm in Chrome 43.  Let me try 44 and see what happens. (I'd prefer for this to work cross-browser, but that'd be good for testing)

Comment: Yes, Canary (45) works perfectly.  Could this be an issue with V8?

Comment: Muhammad, that's exactly the version It failed in for me.  It's possible that this is a problem with my computer.  Let me try a reboot and see where that gets me.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit not particularly helpful, thanks

Comment: when i write version 1 in `console.debug()` then it works. But it's worse when i write it in `console.log()`. I'm narrowing down it. i'm using chrome Version 43.0.2357.132 m

Comment: When I run `console.debug()`, I get `function anonymous(eturn) function anonymous(eturn)`.  The reboot didn't do anything.  I'm in the same version of Chrome as you.  What operating system are you on?  I'm Windows 8.1.

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe it's the operating system's way of running the C in the javascript engine.

Comment: For what its worth, I got the same result using Chrome 43.0.2357.134 m on Windows 7. I get the same result in Chrome 43.0.2357.134 on Mac OS X 10.

Comment: Amy, to clarify, you got my result or Muhammad's?

Comment: Sorry, yours, Scelesto.

Comment: Thanks.  Does anyone know anything about how V8 or another javascript engine is compiled?  That might provide information about what is causing Muhammad's system to work differently.

Comment: @Scelesto i need to share a long string which i can't paste here. can you come one chat

Comment: Sure, but I don't know how.

Comment: or i'm pasting in the answer section, i will update the answer later that why it's happening...

Comment: Still doesn't work, although it doesn't do the weird "urn" or "eturn" things now.  This also wouldn't be a solution anyway because my parameters say not to use spaces or newlines.

Comment: no no, i want you to notice something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84219/discussion-between-muhammad-imran-and-scelesto).

Comment: @Scelesto can u plz come on chat by clicking the link

Comment: I didn't experience any viewing pleasure even in your beautified version. Shakes head. How do people work like this.

Comment: It's not supposed to be beautiful.  It's supposed to prove my hypothesis.  You try writing code that follows those parameters and looks good.  `alert()` is probably about as far is you're going to get.

Comment: This has nothing to do with anonymous functions. You would get the same result if those were named.

Comment: Sebastian please explain.

Comment: By the way @Amy it seems that Muhammad's system might not be working differently from mine.  I think there was a miscommunication.

Comment: It's just a displaying issue on the console. `function anonymous(urn)` the `urn` is part of a `return`statement from your code. Chrome just messes displaying the correct arguments up for whatever reason. That doesn't mean that the code doesn't work the same. Just name all anonymous functions and look up their code in the VM and you will see that the functions and their arguments are perfectly fine.

Comment: Sebastian, it DOESN'T work the same.  It (the real function) runs properly in Canary, and not in regular Chrome.  It runs properly with the newline, and not without it.  I've tested this to no end.  The reason why I posted it with the console.log is because that's much more interactive for users trying to figure out what I'm doing.

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry Sebastian, I think they're separate problems.  When I externalize the functions (even when logging doesn't work) everything runs perfectly.  Internally they're still having trouble, but I think you're right that the logging is mostly just a problem with the log function.

Comment: All 3 versions work exactly the same for me regardless of what the console shows and if the functions are named or not. What kind of error do you receive when using the getprop and setprop methods?

Comment: It doesn't throw an error in that function (the errors occur later when referencing occurs); the function thinks its parameters are undefined. (Although this also seems to depend on the browser).

Comment: I'm going to try and rewrite the function to make the functionality work (forget about logging for the moment, nobody seems to have a good answer.)

Comment: Rewriting seems to be working.  Thanks @SebastianNette.

Comment: On a sidenote: `console.log(arguments);` or `console.log([getprop, setprop]);` would have probably shown the correct arguments for your functions. Or even `console.log(getprop.toString(),setprop.toString())`

Comment: Actually, I tried all three of those, and none worked... :/  Not sure why.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a bug which has already been reported and resolved

Comment: Has that been confirmed with Firefox?

Comment: I just checked myself with Firefox and this seems to have been "fixed," as in all three lines of code produce the same result, but none of the three of them produce the original intended result. However, because this was clearly an intentional choice of the developers, it's no reason to keep this open. Opera and Safari are working nominally. I'll check Edge, and then close.

Comment: Edge is working nominally. I'll edit the question in case anyone stumbles upon it, and then close.

Comment: Oh, I guess I don't have the power to do that. I suppose it could still remain open for continuing Firefox development.

Comment: Please don't put a solution in your question; post it as an answer instead.  [Will Kunkel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453273/will-kunkel) has already provided [a CW answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38065476/3476191); you may [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38065476/edit) that answer as needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern versions of Chrome, Opera, Safari, and Edge are working nominally.

Firefox still logs functions with no arguments, but since it now does so uniformly between all three versions of the code, it seems the bug has been addressed. I take it that this display choice is a conscious choice on the part of the developers.

It would still be nice to see further documentation on this issue from Mozilla, or even nicer if Firefox would join Chrome, Opera, Safari, and Edge by displaying function arguments correctly.